# LXDE System Tray: Skype, Pidgin and other active applications not showing up

Tags: 12.10, skype, lxde, pidgin, system-tray

I'm running LXDE, and I've noticed that applications that normally minimize to the tray are not showing up in the try in LXDE.

I don't have a specific system tray applet installed, and can't seem to find one online.

Skype, and Pidgin just become background processes when run, and I have to look them up with `htop` or `ps` to close them, or activate them again.

Is there any system tray package in the repos that will give me a system tray?

EDIT: lxpanel is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually turns out I had to dig deeper than thought.

I had to click into the 'TaskBar (Window List)' in the list of applets. I was presented with another list of applets, and was able to use that to get System Tray reinserted onto my task bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a

```
sudo apt-get install lxpanel
```

You should be fine.

Comment: 'lxpanel is already at the latest version' Is there a specific applet I should add to the panel?

Comment: It's been a little while for me with lxde, but isn't there something like a notification area on the panel?

Comment: Not that I can find.

Comment: I found a site that suggests that xfce4-panel interferes with lxde. take a look http://linuxftw.weebly.com/lubuntu-1110-installation-guide.html

Comment: Look at my answer. It looks like System Tray is the name of the applet.